# Setting up a computer lab w/ wireless bridge for network administration/pen testing practice

Tags: networking, vlan, windows-server, wireless-bridge

So I'm trying to setup a computer lab to practice network administration. My setup is:

- Home ISP router (assigned to 192.168.0.1)
- Separate Wireless Router set to bridge mode (b/c my girlfriend would kill me if I dragged a cable through the house)
- Cisco Catalyst 3550 Switch (Layer 3 switch)
- PC w/ Win Server 2012 installed
- 3 computers w/ various versions of Windows installed (all plugged into the Cisco Switch)

What I'm trying to do is separate my computer lab from the rest of the network for admin/pen testing practice (I've been told the best way to do this is w/ a vlan). So far I've been able to get all the computers to wirelessly bridge to my ISP router, but one PC on the switch can't ping another PC on the switch (I found out that disabling firewall on computers allows them to ping each other, but obviously this is not a viable solution as I can't be running client computers without firewall enabled).

So I guess my questions are as follows:

- Should I be setting up VLANs on my switch to keep the networks separate?
- Will this allow Windows Server to handle DHCP for my computer lab while still allowing my ISP router to handle DHCP for everything else in the house?
- Will the pinging issue resolve itself once I setup DNS/DHCP on Windows Server?
- Will setting up a VLAN on the switch still allow everything connected to it to get access to the internet?  Do I need to make sure the IP address of my wireless bridge is in the same network as the VLAN for my lab?

I know this is a pretty loaded question, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been able to get a Windows Domain setup in VirtualBox, but having difficulty getting it setup on a physical level.

Thanks in Advance for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Should I be setting up VLANs on my switch to keep the networks separate?

A. Yes, setting up multiple VLANs will separate two networks.

Will this allow Windows Server to handle DHCP for my computer lab while still allowing my ISP router to handle DHCP for everything else in the house?

A. You can have DHCP server on each VLAN, your Router will provide DHCP to devices in your house, and you Windows server can provide DHCP for Lab devices.

Will the pinging issue resolve itself once I setup DNS/DHCP on Windows Server?

A. No, you will need to allow Pings or disable firewall. You can setup Group Policy to update firewall.

Will setting up a VLAN on the switch still allow everything connected to it to get access to the internet? 
Do I need to make sure the IP address of my wireless bridge is in the same network as the VLAN for my lab?

A. No. If  your Router supports multiple VLANs, you can setup Internet access for the Second Lab VLAN. If not, you can use your Windows Server, and have it connect to both Networks. The IP Address of Bridge will not matter, it not routing any Network.